# Extract part of float type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to extract part of float type in SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestPhoneNumbers]
(
    [phone] [float] NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO [TestPhoneNumbers]
VALUES  (1111122222,'GOOD'),
        (3333344444,'GOOD'),
        (5555566666,'GOOD'),
        (7777788888,'GOOD'),
        (1,'INCORRECT');

SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), phone, 128), 4, 10)
FROM TestPhoneNumbers;
```

This query returned unexpected characters

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 10)
FROM TestPhoneNumbers;
```

And this query returned error

> Argument data type float is invalid for argument 1 of `substring` function.

My question is how to get rightmost 5 characters from phone if the length of phone is greater than 5 characters? i.e. if the phone is `123456789`, expected result is `56789`.

Comment: Don't store the phone number as a float.  Use a string.  Floats are not exact.  But phone numbers are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your data!  Phone numbers should not be stored as `float`.  That is just the wrong representation -- an imprecise number to represent a precise phone number?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestPhoneNumbers](
    [phone] varchar(255) NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO [TestPhoneNumbers] (phone, type)
    VALUES ('1111122222', 'GOOD'),
           ('3333344444', 'GOOD'),
           ('5555566666', 'GOOD'),
           ('7777788888', 'GOOD'),
           ('1', 'INCORRECT');
```

Then you can use `RIGHT()`:

```
SELECT RIGHT(phone, 5) as right5
FROM TestPhoneNumbers;
```

Comment: Agree that float should not be used for phone. But, this table has been in prod for few years and changing the 'phone' to varchar is not a possibility at this time. Is it not possible to modify the phone data(without changing to varchar) and then retrieve the part of the phone number?

Comment: @nagiahs . . .You can use `cast()`.  But having this as a `float` is a bug waiting to happen and the data should be fixed.  At the very least, you can change it to `numeric(18,0)` or something like that.